# Sharepoint API folder search endpoint & query not working

Tags: search, sharepoint-rest-api, folder, sharepoint-search, graph-api

I'm building an integration with Sharepoint via Make (formerly Integromat). The native Make module for searching sharepoint does not identify the folder & returns no results. I have to enter a path relative to https://graph.microsoft.com - For instance https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/children
The query I input is just the folder name. What am I missing:
[Query example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R92ru.png)
[image: Sharepoint results with duplicate folders being created after no search results]

Comment: It's not clear if you want to use the SharePoint search api or Microsoft Graph. Have you confirmed that the api endpoint you wish to use returns results using a tool like Postman?